# pm2 starts two duplicate processes with a different version

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 version `4.2.3`

When I run this command: `pm2 start node launchers/engine_launcher.js --name "engine"`, it starts the following:

```
id  │ name                           │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12  │ engine                         │ default     │ 0.34.0  │ fork    │ 893
13  │ engine                         │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 8946
```

I want only one process to be started.
If I `pm2 delete engine`, both go away.

`launchers/engine_launcher.js` is a regular javascript script.

What causes this problem? How can I start only one version of my script?

This doesn't happen for other scripts, only this one.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `start node app.js` use just `start app.js`.

Comment: This works for me. Can you explain what really happens when we use `start`?

Comment: Will this still work if app.js doesn't have a shebang line?

Comment: I think it means `pm2 start app.js` starts app.js inside node directly instead of running a second node process, think it works without a shebang line

Answer (score 3):

`pm2 delete 12` is one way to do it.